# Getting "xsltCompilePattern" on trying pass parameters to XSLT file from Python code

Tags: python, xslt

transform.xslt:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:param name="tag"/>
    <xsl:param name="uniqueID"/>
    <xsl:param name="uniqueIDValue"/>
    <xsl:param name="attributeToBeAdded"/>
    <xsl:param name="attributeValue"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="{ $tag }[@{ $uniqueID }={ $uniqueIDValue }]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:attribute name="{$attributeToBeAdded}">{$attributeValue}</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Python code:

```
xml = ET.parse('ABC.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('transform.xslt')
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = xslt(xml, tag=ET.XSLT.strparam("wire"),uniqueID=ET.XSLT.strparam("name"),uniqueIDValue=ET.XSLT.strparam("ABC"),attributeToBeAdded=ET.XSLT.strparam("Fr"),attributeValue=ET.XSLT.strparam("351"))
```

On running the python code to pass arguments to the xslt file, i am getting the following error

**XSLTParseError: xsltCompilePattern : failed to compile '{ $tag }[@{ $uniqueID }={ $uniqueIDValue }]'**

I am pretty sure i am making some syntax error, help needed with the right syntax..Thank you

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you expect there, the usual Python XSLT supports is based on libxslt which supports XSLT 1 so I don't understand why you have used the tags for the XSLT versions 2.0 and 3.0. Furthermore, in any version of XSLT, and in any way you set parameters, there is no support for the `match` way you try, the closest would be using an XSLT 3 processor together with static parameters and shadow attributes e.g. `_match`. That would require using an XSLT 3 processor like the Saxon-C 1.2.1 and its Python binding although I am not sure currently how well static parameters are supported in that setup.

The text value template syntax `{$attributeValue}` is also only supported by XSLT 3 processors and even then only if you set `expand-text="yes"` in the XSLT.

So the only right use in terms of XSLT 1 is `xsl:attribute name="{$attributeToBeAdded}"`.